# ampersand problem with wordpress categories

Tags: php, wordpress, ampersand

I have an array of categories, some with an & i.e. events & entertainment.
My script imports these categories and gets the ID of each using its name.
i.e.: `$cat_id = array(get_cat_id($linearray[0]),get_cat_id($linearray[1]),get_cat_id($linearray[2]),get_cat_id($linearray[3]));`
My script then adds a post to wp using these category ID's.
My problem is that categories from my import with the & are not imported.
These same categories (when an email notice is sent) break the email at the &.
Is there a simple workaround to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are writing post, instead of `&` you can write `&amp;` there and it will be translated to `&` without any problems.

Also you could use the `str_replace` function to convert that to `&amp;` eg:

```
$new_text = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $your_string);
```

Comment: unfortunately there are hundreds of existing 'permalinked' categories.. and this issue relates to an import that adds itself to them.

Comment: @InnateDev: That should not happen though, because wordpress automatically converts them to html entities. That's strange.

Comment: will this be able to match the actual category name using the get_cat_id function: get_cat_id('Events &amp; Entertainment');

Comment: yes this works: $catname_one = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $linearray[0]);
   $catname_two = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $linearray[1]);
   $catname_three = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $linearray[2]);
   $catname_four = str_replace('&', '&amp;', $linearray[3]);
   $cat_id = array(get_cat_id($catname_one),get_cat_id($catname_two),get_cat_id($catname_three),get_cat_id($catname_four));
   print_r($cat_id);

Answer (score 0):

I think for some circumstances I used my own custom sluggify function for Wordpress:

```
function sluggify($text) {
   $text = strtolower(htmlentities($text));
   $text = str_replace("&amp;", "and", $text);
   $text = str_replace("andamp;", "and", $text);
   $text = str_replace(get_html_translation_table(), "-", $text);
   $text = str_replace(" ", "-", $text);
   $text = preg_replace("/[-]+/i", "-", $text);
   return $text;
}
```

Note the two repetitive lines:

```
$text = str_replace("&amp;", "and", $text);
$text = str_replace("andamp;", "and", $text);
```

Although repetitive, it's quite necessary!

For the ignorant commenter below - it's a reusable function where you can pass in any string value and it will be slugged. So, workable for the above case.

Comment: How does this solve the given problem? Does this replace anything during the import of categories?

Comment: This comment was provided to me in a SO review queue as you've added an answer to a really old question. There is no reason to be rude, just give a bit more context about the connection between the question (where a problem during the import of categories for WP is mentioned) and your answer (where neither an importer nor categories nor WordPress are mentioned)

Comment: Users of Wordpress will run into this issue where the import won't work because the category slug does not accept & ampersands as they are slugged so they need to be dropped. You need to sluggify the category slug as you import.

Comment: It's a function. You pass in your Category Name, e.g., Events & Entertainment, and the output will be events-and-entertainment. It's likely that his import was working, just not under the right Category slug, so he may have had events-entertainment. This is the behaviour of Wordpress' default sluggify method - so you need to tweak before you import.

Answer (score 0):

There is a WP built-in function for this:

```
$new_text = wp_specialchars_decode($your_string);
```

From the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_specialchars_decode/):

> Converts a number of HTML entities into their special characters.
> Specifically deals with: &, <, >, ", and ‘.